# Is it possible to declare mutable and immutable values/bindings simultaneously?

Tags: f#, tuples, mutable, let

For example I want to declare

```
let len, (*mutable*) i =
            if s.Length >= 2 && s.[0] = '0' && (s.[1] = 'x' || s.[1] = 'X') then
                (s.Length - 2, 2)
            else (s.Length, 0)
```

constant binding len and mutable i, is it possible ?

**Added :** 
I will use references then

```
    let len, i =
        if s.Length >= 2 && s.[0] = '0' && (s.[1] = 'x' || s.[1] = 'X') then
            (s.Length - 2, ref 2)
        else (s.Length, ref 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `mutable` applies to the entire `let` binding. You'll have to do:

```
let len, i = ...
let mutable i = i
```

Comment: Right. `ref` is a distinct type, not a `mutable` value on the stack.